# Is there a way I can get the new column value based on previous rows without using loop in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a data table which has two columns time in and time out as shown below.

```
TimeIn TimeOut
01:23AM 01:45AM
01:34AM 01:53AM
01:43AM 01:59AM
02:01AM 02:09AM
02:34AM 03:11AM
02:39AM 02:48AM
02:56AM 03:12AM
```

I need to create a third column named 'Counter' which updates in a way that when the TimeIn of ith occurance is more than TimeOut of (i-1)th then that counter remains same else increases to 1. Consider it as people assigned for task so if a person is free after his/her time out then he/she can take up the job. Also if at a particular instance more than one counter is free then I need to take the first of them which got free so the above table would look like this.

```
TimeIn TimeOut Counter
01:23AM 01:45AM 1
01:34AM 01:53AM 2
01:43AM 01:59AM 3
02:01AM 02:09AM 1 (in this case 1,2,3 all are also free but 1 became free first)
02:34AM 03:11AM 2 (in this case 1,2,3 all are also free but 2 became free first)
02:39AM 02:48AM 3 (in this case 1 is also free but 3 became free first)
02:56AM 03:12AM 1 (in this case 3 is also free but 1 became free first)
```

I was hoping if there could be a way in pandas to do it without loop since my database could be large but please let me know even if there is a way where it could be achieved efficiently using a loop as well should be fine.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @ScottBoston Hi Scott, no actually. Since 02:01AM is occurring at the time when all the counters are free but I used 1 because it became free first. I will just update with this info as well. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out an efficient way with native Pandas-methods. But if I'm not completely mistaken, a [heap queue](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html) seems to be an adequate tool for the problem.

With

```
df =
    TimeIn  TimeOut
0  01:23AM  01:45AM
1  01:34AM  01:53AM
2  01:43AM  01:59AM
3  02:01AM  02:09AM
4  02:34AM  03:11AM
5  02:39AM  02:48AM
6  02:56AM  03:12AM
```

and

```
for col in ("TimeIn", "TimeOut"):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

this

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

w_count = 1
counter = [1]
heap = []
w_time_out, w = df.TimeOut[0], 1
for time_in, time_out in zip(
    df.TimeIn.tolist()[1:], df.TimeOut.tolist()[1:]
):
    if time_in > w_time_out:
        heappush(heap, (time_out, w))
        counter.append(w)
        w_time_out, w = heappop(heap)
    else:
        w_count += 1
        counter.append(w_count)
        if time_out > w_time_out:
            heappush(heap, (time_out, w_count))
        else:
            heappush(heap, (w_time_out, w))
            w_time_out, w = time_out, w_count
```

produces the `counter`-list

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Regarding your input data: You don't have complete timestamps, so `pd.to_datetime` uses the current day as date part. So if the range of your times isn't contained in one day you'll run into trouble.

**EDIT**: Fixed a mistake in the last `else`-branch.

Comment: Thanks Timus. Yes for now I considered it for a day only but you are right in the whole data set I have different dates as well. Do you mean that this may throw error if the data has multiple dates?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh If you have proper timestamps the algorithm should work fine.

Comment: Yes, I had a different Date column so I just concatenated them and then converted them to datetime like you have shown. Thanks to the edit too.  Works great. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Just one question or tip if I may. Do you think this idea of using the first free counter is optimal? I mean do you think there could be another optimal may in which we can have lesser counters?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh You could just use any random free counter, irregardless of its history. But that wouldn't change the number of counters used. I'm not a 100% sure, but I don't think there's a way to reduce the number of counters.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I thought so too. Just wanted to get a second opinion. I also thought with real life example like drivers that who ever gets free first but then it wasn't lowering the count with whichever example I compared. So I think I am good with the algorithm here and your code. Thanks again bud!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I'm including a pandas/numpy based solution. Performance is roughly 3x better (I saw 12s vs 34s for 10 million records) than the heapq based one, but implementation is significantly harder to follow. Unless you really need the performance, I'd recommend [@Timus solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750135/is-there-a-way-i-can-get-the-new-column-value-based-on-previous-rows-without-usi/68758246#68758246).

The idea here is:

1. We identify sessions where we have to increment the counter. We can immediately assign counter values to these sessions.
2. For the remaining sessions, we create a sequence of sessions that the same worker handles. We can then map any session to a "root session" where the worker was created.

To accomplish step (2):

1. We get two lists of session IDs, one sorted by start time and the other end time.
2. Pair each session start with the least recent session end. This corresponds to the earliest available worker taking on the next incoming request.
3. Work up the tree to map any given session to the first session handled by that worker.

```
# setup
text = StringIO(
    """
TimeIn TimeOut
01:23AM 01:45AM
01:34AM 01:53AM
01:43AM 01:59AM
02:01AM 02:09AM
02:34AM 03:11AM
02:39AM 02:48AM
02:56AM 03:12AM 
""".strip()
)

sessions = pd.read_csv(text, sep=" ", parse_dates=["TimeIn", "TimeOut"])

# transform the data from wide format to long format
# event_log has the following columns:
#   - Session: corresponding to the index of the input data
#   - EventType: either TimeIn or TimeOut
#   - EventTime: the event's time value
event_log = pd.melt(
    sessions.rename_axis(index="Session").reset_index(),
    id_vars=["Session"],
    value_vars=["TimeIn", "TimeOut"],
    var_name="EventType",
    value_name="EventTime",
)
# sort the entire log by time
event_log.sort_values("EventTime", inplace=True, kind="mergesort")

# concurrency is the number of active workers at the time of that log entry
concurrency = event_log["EventType"].replace({"TimeIn": 1, "TimeOut": -1}).cumsum()
# new workers occur when the running maximum concurrency increases
new_worker = concurrency.cummax().diff().astype(bool)
new_worker_sessions = event_log.loc[new_worker, "Session"]

root_session = np.empty_like(sessions.index)
root_session[new_worker_sessions] = new_worker_sessions

# we could use the `sessions` DataFrame to avoid searching, but we'd need to sort on TimeOut
new_session = event_log.query("~@new_worker & (EventType == 'TimeIn')")["Session"]
old_session = event_log.query("~@new_worker & (EventType == 'TimeOut')")["Session"]

# Pair each session start with the session that ended least recently
root_session[new_session] = old_session[: new_session.shape[0]]

# Find the root session
# maybe something can be optimized here?
while not np.array_equal((_root_session := root_session.take(root_session)), root_session):
    root_session = _root_session

counter = np.empty_like(root_session)
counter[new_worker_sessions] = np.arange(start=1, stop=new_worker_sessions.shape[0] + 1)
sessions["Counter"] = counter.take(root_session)
```

Quick bit of code to generate more fake data:

```
N = 10 ** 6
start = pd.Timestamp("2021-08-12T01:23:00")
_base = pd.date_range(start=start, periods=N, freq=pd.Timedelta(1, "seconds"))

time_in = (
    _base.values
    + np.random.exponential(1000, size=N).astype("timedelta64[ms]")
    + np.random.exponential(10000, size=N).astype("timedelta64[ns]")
    + np.timedelta64(1, "ms")
)
time_out = (
    time_in
    + np.random.exponential(10, size=N).astype("timedelta64[s]")
    + np.random.exponential(1000, size=N).astype("timedelta64[ms]")
    + np.random.exponential(10000, size=N).astype("timedelta64[ns]")
    + np.timedelta64(1, "s")
)

sessions = (
    pd.DataFrame({"TimeIn": time_in, "TimeOut": time_out})
    .sort_values("TimeIn")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Comment: Nice! Still have to wrap my head around it to understand it completely.